# `emerge --changed-use` does not work for PHP_INI_VERSION

Tags: gentoo, administration

All the gentoo docs on installing PHP[1][2] mentions that I should add a line to make.conf to use the 'production' php.ini

```
PHP_INI_VERSION="production"
```

but that does not seems to do anything... what else should I do to 'enable' that change on the system?

Edit: @terdon pointed out to my blindness, the 1st link says what i should run after editing make.conf... but it does nothing

```
# grep ^display_errors /usr/share/doc/php-5.4.13/*
/usr/share/doc/php-5.4.13/php.ini-production:display_errors = Off
/usr/share/doc/php-5.4.13/php.ini-development:display_errors = On

# grep PHP /etc/make.conf
PHP_INI_VERSION="production"

# emerge --ask --changed-use --deep @world
These are the packages that would be merged, in order:
Calculating dependencies... done!
Nothing to merge; would you like to auto-clean packages? [Yes/No] y

# grep ^display_errors /etc/php/apache2-php5.4/php.ini 
display_errors = On
```

[1] http://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/PHP‎

[2] http://www.gentoo.org/proj/en/php/php-installing.xml#doc_chap3

Comment: Did you run `emerge --ask --changed-use --deep @world` as suggested in the first link you posted?

Comment: thanks @terdon but it did not work for the php ini. I added more information, and updated the title.